# Find $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ where $S_k=1^k+2^k...+p^k$ for $(p-1)|k$ with $S_k\equiv a\equiv b\pmod{p}$ & $0\le a<p$ and $-p< b\le 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

The question goes as follows:

Let $S_k$ be the sum of $1^k + 2^k ... + p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ is a multiple of $p-1.$

Find 2 integers "$a$" and "$b$" where:

- $S_k \equiv a \equiv b \pmod{p}$
- and $0 \le a < p$ and $-p < b \le 0$.

My logic is to start by using Fermat's Little Thm to simplify things, but i don't really know how to start that.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun can I still use this thread for my question or should I just make a new one

Comment: It's best if you [edit] the question. A separate thread would not be received very well and is likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Using Fermat's little theorem is the right way to go. For $1\le n < p$, what is $n^k\mod{p}$? How about $p^k$?